# Extract from teamcity database concerning tests (durations , status ..etc )

Tags: database, testing, teamcity, devops

Extract from teamCity test  database information ( durations of tests per month , years , etc ) , i want to query teamcity db .. any help to find scripts to query the database of teamcity to get all the informations that i need about tests excuted .